# using Mailchimp for WP/GravityForms notifications

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp, gravity-forms-plugin

We have a website and a MailChimp mailing list. When people register for an account on the website using a GravityForms form, we would like for that same registration action to add them to the mailing list. Do this is quite straight-forward: One simply adds a feed under the form's Settings->MailChimp tab.

We would also like Notifications, such as 'Activation link to registered user', to also be sent via MailChimp since we have customized templates there. I do not see any way to do this - am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not missing anything but you are thinking wrong. There does not have any connection between WP notification & MailChimp.

> MailChimp does not have any authorization to send WP 'Activation link to
>   registered user'

But you can customize WP default notification email. and can sync WP user with Mailchimp

Maybe you understand what I mean.

Comment: mrhossen - Thanks for the reply. I was reflecting on the question while lying in bed and came to the same conclusion.